# Simulated "hard" cape/cloak

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

For example something like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I'm not sure how these "hard"(?) cloths work in real life. In Blender my cloth always feels very soft:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: did you try raising stiffness?